# Having problems while showing videos inside the app via url in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am having an app in which I want to show videos from `urls` inside the app.

I am using `MPMoviePlayerViewController` for this.

Below is the code I am using but somehow the video is not playing from `urls`.

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://vimeo.com/81889151"];




  playercontroller = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] init];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(finishvideo:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:nil];
[playercontroller.moviePlayer setContentURL:URL];
       [self.view addSubview:playercontroller.view];
```

I searched a lot but couldn't find the correct solution for me.

What is wrong with the code above?

Please help me with this.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The url you are trying to load is a standard webpage.
You'll need to load an iOS accepted format like h264. You could display this movie in a UIWebView. Now the MPMoviePlayer is trying to load an HTML webpage which for obvious reasons wouldn't work.

Loading the video in a UIWebView would work as following:

```
NSString *htmlString = @"<iframe src=\"//player.vimeo.com/video/81889151\" width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\" frameborder=\"0\" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>";

UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:FRAME];
[webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
[self.view addSubview:webView];
```

Comment: How can i use "UIWebView".for displaying video..can u please help me out?

Comment: I have updated my answer explaining how to use a UIWebView do display a Vimeo embed.

Comment: UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:FRAME]; in this line  what is FRAME..??.and where should i put this code...can u plz specify it.....

Comment: You'll have to specify frame yourself using a CGRect. You can place this code anywhere you want depending on when you want to display it. This could be in the viewDidLoad or behind a button action or wherever really.

Comment: my urls are coming from a webservice so how to pass that dynamically in html string?

Answer (score 0):

```
[self.view.layer addSublayer:playercontroller];
[playercontroller play];
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

```
@interface VideoViewController : UIViewController <MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer;

@end

 NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://vimeo.com/81889151"];

    _moviePlayer =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]
                     initWithContentURL:movieURL];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(finishvideo:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:_moviePlayer];

    _moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
    _moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;

    [self.view addSubview:_moviePlayer.view];


    [_moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:NO];
```

Comment: Your code gives me error _itemFailedToPlayToEnd: {
    kind = 1;
    new = 2;
    old = 0;
}

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding as a subview, Try to present the movie player view controller

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://vimeo.com/81889151"];
    playercontroller = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:URL];


[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(finishvideo:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:nil];
 [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:playercontroller];
```

Comment: your code is showing error as given below...samplevideocontroller[3410:60b] _itemFailedToPlayToEnd: {
    kind = 1;
    new = 2;
    old = 0;
}

Comment: If you are getting error using MPMoviePlayerController then you should go for webview.

Here is the code.

  self.videoWebView.delegate = self;
         [self.videoWebView loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head><style>{font-family: helvetica,arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:1.4em; color:#666666; text-decoration: none;}</style></head><body>%@</body></html>",videoURL] baseURL:nil];

Comment: my urls are coming from a webservice so how to pass that dynamically in html string?

Comment: See my code.. I am using videoURL. replace videoURL with your NSURL object. Let me know If it work.